# Organización de hojas de estilos

Tags: html, css, html5

¿Cómo organizo las hojas de estilo? Ahora mismo tengo solo una hoja: `style.css`, que utilizo en mi proyecto.

Mi pregunta es, si es más eficiente agregar los estilos restantes al mismo fichero o crear otro para cada página.

**¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de mejorar la jerarquía de ficheros de un sitio?**

Comment: Esta pregunta así como esta acabara cerrada, pues hay muchas respuestas buenas que se basaran en opiniones. Pero la puedes salvar, por ejemplo, si la transformas en una pregunta de revision de código, done nos muestras lo que tienes, resumido y completo y preguntas: como se puede mejorar este codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu aplicación es sencilla y los estilos que aplicas son bastante similares en todas las páginas, puedes mantener los estilos en un solo archivo `CSS`.

#### Ventajas

- Realizas una sola petición al servidor, por lo que dejas vía libre para otras conexiones.

#### Desventajas

- Si los estilos varían mucho de página en página, cada vez que se carguen los estilos estarás trayendo más de lo necesario.

Si tu diseño es más complejo, tiene una gran cantidad de estilos y quieres separar mejor el código, también podrías separarlo en, al menos, un archivo con los estilos comunes y otro archivo con los estilos específicos de un grupo de páginas similares.

#### Ventajas

- Mejor organización de código.
- El peso total disminuye al traer solo lo necesario.

#### Desventajas

- Vas a realizar dos o más peticiones (las conexiones simultáneas son limitadas) por lo que el tiempo de carga de la página podría incrementarse.

El tema de optimización es complejo. Hay muchos factores adicionales que tomar en cuenta:

- Cache del lado cliente para archivos `CSS` estáticos. Y del lado servidor si, por ejemplo, son generados dinámicamente o compilados con `LESS` o `SASS`.

La sugerencia que te doy es **la siguiente**:

> Comienza con lo que te sea más sencillo en tiempo de desarrollo, es decir, como te parezca mejor organizado dependiendo de tu proyecto. Luego mide el rendimiento y mejóralo según tus propias pruebas.

Comment: Cabe destacar que la W3C dice de forma explícita utilizar identificadores de clase que se adapten a su naturaleza, no a la acción que vayan a hacer. Eso traducido al CSS sería adaptar el estilo a la naturaleza de su contenido. Evitar los famosos identificadores `button red`, `button blue`... etcétera, y simplemente seguir un estructurado sistema de estilos desde el principio. Uno se lo agradece a sí mismo puesto que un código limpio es el propósito de un buen proyecto y a la larga se agradece.